# Yii CGridView Data popoulating Using Search in model

Tags: model, yii

In my project, i am using a cgridview to show records corresponding to the user. name the model i am using is `SupplierResponseMaster`. this model have a relation to another model
named `AccountsCorporate` and the relation is `'corporate' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'AccountsCorporate', 'corporate_id'),`. the search function is

```
public function search()
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id, true);
        $criteria->compare('survey_id', $this->survey_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('corporate_id', $this->corporate_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('user_id', $this->user_id, true);
        $criteria->compare('status', $this->status, true);
        $criteria->compare('common_notes', $this->common_notes, true);
        $criteria->compare('system_rank', $this->system_rank, true);
        $criteria->compare('request_coordinator_rank', $this->request_coordinator_rank, true);
        $criteria->compare('is_short_listed', $this->is_short_listed);
        $criteria->compare('short_listed_date', $this->short_listed_date, true);
        $criteria->compare('is_awarded', $this->is_awarded);
        $criteria->compare('awarded_date', $this->awarded_date, true);
        $criteria->compare('created_by', $this->created_by, true);
        $criteria->compare('created_date', $this->created_date, true);
        $criteria->compare('modified_by', $this->modified_by, true);
        $criteria->compare('modified_date', $this->modified_date, true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                    'criteria' => $criteria,
                ));
    }
```

in my grid view, i need to load the details from the model using the search(or any alternative method) function for the given `user_id` and also get the corporate name from the `AccountCorporate` model using the `corporate_id`. please help me to find a solution for this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the question here exactly?

Comment: @ldg what i am looking for is to populate data on a grid with a custom query.i mean with respect to the user_id i need to display his details. in search() method,i use search to display grid items. but here i need to get details for a particular user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new relation `user` with `'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),`
then to get the details of user for grid you can use `$data->user->name`

For corporate name use `$data->corporate->name`

Comment: is it possible to create a relation between models without having relation in table. i mean without having relation between tables.

Comment: @JaisonJustus Yes, it's possible. Thou it's recommended to create such relation in database as well, as this helps keep consistency of database.

Comment: let me check the scenario and reply asap.